# I don't know which line that I have to put the javascript code in the php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a Add to Cart button.

Javacript code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This item is already in the  
cart.");window.location.href="shoppingcart.php";</script>';
```

I want the javascript code displayed if the item is already in the cart. 
Now, what I want to ask is which line that I must put the javascript in the below code??

Here is the html code:

```
<input type="button" value="Tambah ke Senarai" onclick="addtocart(<?php echo 
$row['no']?>)" />
```

Here is the process of 'add':

```
if($_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0){
    $pid=$_REQUEST['productid'];
    addtocart($pid,1);
    header("location:shoppingcart.php");
    exit();
}

<script language="javascript">
 function addtocart(pid){
    document.form1.productid.value=pid;
    document.form1.command.value='add';
    document.form1.submit();
 } 
</script>
```

Here is the addtocart function :

```
function addtocart($pid,$q){
    if($pid<1 or $q<1) return;

    if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
        if(product_exists($pid))return;
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['qty']=$q;
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['qty']=$q;
    }
}
```

Here is the product_exists function :

```
function product_exists($pid){
    $pid=intval($pid);
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    $flag=0;
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        if($pid==$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid']){
            $flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $flag;
 }
```

Any help/suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It will go inside of `addtocart` function , I guess:

```
if(product_exists($pid)){
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This item is already in the  cart.");window.location.href="cart.php";</script>';
   return;
}
```

Comment: then your condition does not match , try `exit()` instead of return

Comment: I just realize that I cannot add any item to the cart after I changed it using your answer even I've used the exit().